# How do we separately use, maintain & install libraries for python 2.7 and python 3.5 on the same Ubuntu OS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.5

I need to work with Both Python 2.7.12 and python 3.5.2 simultaneously on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Python 3 came pre-installed so I've no idea where it sits, in terms of path to the directory, while python 2 sits in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`.

I found lots of questions on SO and on askubuntu about how to install but nothing about how to use them separately, installing different libraries, and what should I avoid or be careful of, if I maintain this dual python thing for the long term? For example, I usually run pip install  to install a library and I can check that its installed in my python2 directory but how do I install the same package for my python3 without conflicts? Something like: `python3 pip install <package>` ?? Where is the default python3 installed? And how do I call python3 for paths where python is not part of the command for example: `pip freeze`, `sudo-apt get`, etc.?

PS: I've not officially worked with Virtualenv but I've been informed that is usually good for isolating projects within a python language version, rather than isolating two different language versions from each other.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can work with python2 and python3. Python3 should be found in /usr/local/lib/python3.x, to run pythonx writes to the pythonx  scrypt.py

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.x` contains only one directory named dist-packages which itself is empty. So I initially thought its a ghost folder and python3 is not actually installed but when I run `python3` in Terminal, I get: `Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` So I dont know if that path is right..

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: There should *not* be a `/usr/local/lib/python3.5` directory if you're using the system version of Python 3.5.  The system Python would install packages in `/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/` instead.

Comment: Don't bother with a virtual environment unless you have explicit dependency versions (not just the latest up-to-date dependency), do package development or want a stable environment that is allowed to get outdated over the course of time (e.g., a webserver).

Comment: Agree with Evert, the `/usr/lib/` path makes more sense as its a pre-installed package. I'm able to use pip now but there is not dist-packages folder in python3.5 folder.

Comment: Installed pandas in 3.5 to see if dist-packages folder would autogenerate (since pandas is installed in dist-packages in my 2.7), but that didn't happen and now if I search for pandas in `/usr/lib/python3.5/`, there is no pandas file or folder. So, I'm guessing that maynot be the right python3.5. But its weird that there are so many installations in the same OS and things need to just work; I seem to have python3 also preinstalled in my `/usr/lib/` (and no, the pandas I just installed isn't there either). I dont know if that makes ubuntu a robust os or a brittle one.

Comment: `python3.5 -c "import pandas; print(pandas.__path__)"` will tell you where pandas lives. But, for most packages to be used with an OS Python, see if there's a relevant `python3-xyz` package (`python3-pandas` does exist).

Comment: Note: if you ran `pip3.5` without `sudo`, pandas and such are possibly installed in `$HOME/.local/`. Which is fine, unless you need a system-wide installation.

Comment: NB: Ubuntu is fine as a stable environment; you just have to wrap your head around the various Python installations. Besides, you *are* using two different Python versions, one from the OS, one self-installed, so things are not going to be 100% straightforward (90% though, once you got your head wrapped around the basics).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is absolutely no problem, as Python does that for you. You don't need a virtualenv at all.

If you use Ubuntu packages, make sure you use the `python3-` versions for Python 3, and the normal `python-` versions for Python 2.
For example, `python3-numpy` and `python-numpy`.

If you use `pip` to install extra packages, you an either use the `pip` script with the version number appended: `pip2.7` or `pip3.5`, or, my preferred method, call `pip` as a module for the respective Python executable:

```
python2.7 -m pip install <whatever>
```

and

```
python3.5 -m pip install <whatever>
```

Other than that, there should not be any issue: Python stores the packages in completely separate directories, and each Python executable only uses its respective directive.

Do *not* fiddle around with `PYTHONPATH`, unless you really know what you're doing. This has the danger of setting your `PYTHONPATH` to a directory with Python 2.7 modules and then using Python 3.5 to run things.

---

If you start from scratch, you may need to install `pip` first.

For the *system* Python(s), use the relevant package:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

For your locally installed Python(s), use the built-in bootstrapper module:

```
pythonx.y -m ensurepip
```

---

Note on the OS-installed Python executables:

Python 3.5 lives at /usr/bin/python3.5, Python 2.7 (the OS one) at /usr/bin/python2.7. 
You could even use the OS 2.7 one *next to* your locally installed `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` (and confuse yourself when a package can't be found because you used the wrong one).
Or install Python 3.6 next to Python 3.5 (provided you've used `make altinstall`, so `python3` doesn't get overwritten).

This is also why you don't really want to run `pip` (or even `pip2.7`) *as is*: `pip2.7` may get you the system one, instead of the one in `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7`, depending on your `PATH`.

(The same goes for the `python2.7` executable, so if you need to specify the full path `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` to run that one (or have an alias), the same holds for `pip2.7`. If, on the other hand, `/usr/local/bin` is *first* on your `PATH`, you should in principle never run into the same `pip` and `python` executables.)

Comment: `python2.7 -m pip freeze` and `python3.5 -m pip freeze`, return `/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip` and `/usr/bin/python3.5: No module named pip` respectively. However, `pip2.7 freeze` works while `pip3.5 freeze` returns `pip3.5: command not found`. Thoughts?

Comment: For 3.5, try `sudo apt install python3-pip`. For Python 2.7, try `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m ensurepip`. Looks like Ubuntu doesn't install pip by default.

Comment: The `ensurepip` bootstrapper module has to be run only once, to install `pip` itself (and only for your self-installed python2.7, since that doesn't come with a package. What is the full path for `pip2.7` you used above?

Comment: @DrConfuse I've added the pip installation steps to my answer in the cases where one's starting from scratch.

Comment: Evert, pip2.7 corresponds to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. Thanks to `sudo apt install python3-pip`, my python3.5 -m pip install <stuff> works now. Python2.7 already had a working pip, so I'm not sure if I need to run ensurepip for installation. I'm not sure if you are referring to pip being a package itself, because I checked in both pythons and only 2.7 had a pip folder in the dist-packages, while 3.5 had neither a dist-packages nor a pip folder.

Comment: @Evert: Ubuntu doesn't install pip for a reason: they don't want any tool other than apt messing around in /usr.  The correct way to run pip on Ubuntu is from inside a virtualenv.

Comment: @DrConfuse If you have a `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7`, then I'm surprised there is no pip module for Python 2.7. The `python2.7 -m ensurepip` option might still install the module, so then you could *also* run `python2.7 -m pip <whatever>`, next to `pip2.7 <whatever>`. The former uses the module, the latter the standalone script you have now, but they are equivalent. (And I guess that `pip2.7 install pip --upgrade` would also install the module.)

Comment: @Kevin That's a point which make sense. Would have you a statement (from Ubuntu) to back that up. I would still not use a virtualenv, but let pip3 install things in $HOME, with `--user` (and I think that's the default when not using `sudo` or friends to run an OS-installed pip).